# if subquery returns no rows fetch all the records or ignore that condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT DISTINCT VISION_SBU, SBU_DESCRIPTION
  FROM (SELECT 'All' VISION_SBU, 'All' SBU_DESCRIPTION, 1 sort_order FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ALPHA_SUB_TAB, ALPHA_SUBTAB_DESCRIPTION, case when ALPHA_SUB_TAB = 'NA' then 99999 else row_number() over (order by ALPHA_SUB_TAB) +1 end sort_order
          FROM ALPHA_SUB_TAB
         WHERE ALPHA_TAB = 3) H1
where VISION_SBU in (
select t2.sbu from vision_user t1 left outer join VU_RESTRICT_SBU t2
on t1.vision_id = t2.vision_id
where t1.vision_id = #VISION_ID#)
and  account_officers in  (
select t2.account_officer from vision_user t1 left outer join VU_RESTRICT_SBU t2
on t1.vision_id = t2.vision_id
where t1.vision_id = #VISION_ID#)
and  vision_ouc in  (
select t2.vision_ouc from vision_user t1 left outer join VU_RESTRICT_SBU t2
on t1.vision_id = t2.vision_id
where t1.vision_id = #VISION_ID#)
```

when the where clause sub query matches the filter data only that data should be displayed,
when the where clause sub query returns no rows then that filter should not be applied for the where clause.

Also we have multiple queries so request you to a logic with the optimized solution.

Comment: Stackoverflow is no code writing service. Please ask your query more specific and show what you have tried so far. In order to check whether a condition is satisfied, you can use EXISTS.

Comment: if i use exists taking so much time.if subquery have record i need to fetch specific record.if dont have record i need to fetch all the records in the main select.(i need to ignore that condition.

Comment: Your query does not work as the `vision_ouc` and `account_officer` columns are undefined in the outer query [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2ec5010e4720f7283bfd7e4a7291a639).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter for when `VISION_SUB = 'All'` to short-cut the `IN` filter.

Additionally, if you expect the `sbu`, `account_officer` and `vision_ouc` matches to be in the same row then you should not be using multiple `IN` filters and should do it all in the same sub-query.

Something like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       VISION_SBU,
       SBU_DESCRIPTION
FROM   ( SELECT 'All' VISION_SBU,
                'All' SBU_DESCRIPTION,
                1 sort_order
         FROM   DUAL
       UNION ALL
         SELECT ALPHA_SUB_TAB,
                ALPHA_SUBTAB_DESCRIPTION,
                case when ALPHA_SUB_TAB = 'NA' then 99999 else row_number() over (order by ALPHA_SUB_TAB) +1 end sort_order
         FROM   ALPHA_SUB_TAB
         WHERE  ALPHA_TAB = 3
       ) H1
WHERE  (  VISION_SBU = 'All'
       OR EXISTS ( select 1
                   from   vision_user t1
                          left outer join VU_RESTRICT_SBU t2
                          on t1.vision_id = t2.vision_id
                   where t1.vision_id        = #VISION_ID#
                   AND   h1.VISION_SBU       = t2.sbu
                   AND   h1.account_officers = t2.account_officer
                   AND   h1.vision_ouc       = t2.vision_ouc
                 )
       )
```

However, I'm not sure that the `account_officers` or `vision_ouc` columns exist in your outer `h1` query so you need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a case for this as

```
case when  (select count(t2.sbu) from vision_user t1 left outer join VU_RESTRICT_SBU t2
on t1.vision_id = t2.vision_id
where t1.vision_id = #VISION_ID#) > 0 then 
VISION_SBU in (
select t2.sbu from vision_user t1 left outer join VU_RESTRICT_SBU t2
on t1.vision_id = t2.vision_id
where t1.vision_id = #VISION_ID#) else 1 = 1 end
```

But performance-wise, this is not a good idea.

If I were you, I am using a function/ SP using temporary tables.

Comment: if subquery return multiple record we are getting error([Error] Execution (49: 18): ORA-00905: missing keyword) VISION_SBU in (
select t2.sbu from vision_user t1 left outer join VU_RESTRICT_SBU t2
on t1.vision_id = t2.vision_id
where t1.vision_id = #VISION_ID#)

Comment: account_officers . vision_ouc also should be in your main table H1, right?
Actually, I try to provide you with a solution to ignore null records only :). I'll check and let you know

Comment: did you try this way
case when  (select count(t2.sbu) from vision_user t1 left outer join VU_RESTRICT_SBU t2
on t1.vision_id = t2.vision_id
where t1.vision_id = #VISION_ID#) > 0 then 
VISION_SBU in (
select t2.sbu from vision_user t1 left outer join VU_RESTRICT_SBU t2
on t1.vision_id = t2.vision_id
where t1.vision_id = #VISION_ID#) else 1 = 1 end